# EJS loop through nested array in resultData

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ejs

I am trying to grab a JSON object from a Mongo collection that has nested arrays in it. The plantResult object in my database looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc97b175c3e221086646b95"),
    "username" : "test-user",
    "tentname" : "Tent1",
    "startdate" : "2018-06-06",
    "notes" : "No notes",
    "vegnutrients" : "grow1,grow2",
    "vegnutrientsvalues" : [
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5bc68c91296be70081afdeff"),
                "nutrientname" : "grow",
                "description" : "Test Grow",
                "week1" : 6,
                "week2" : 6,
                "week3" : 12,
                "week4" : 14,
                "week5" : 8,
                "week6" : 0,
                "week7" : 0,
                "week8" : 0,
                "week9" : 0,
                "week10" : 0
            }
        ],
        [ ]
    ],
    "growmedium" : "soil"
}
```

and I render the page using EJS and Express in my router file like this:

```
res.render('viewplant', { username: uname, tentname: tentname, resultData: plantResult } );
```

and then I try to iterate thru the results and grab the `week1` values for each item in the `vegnutrientsvalues` array by attempting this:

```
<script>
  var vegnutrients = "<%= resultData[0].vegnutrients %>";
  //delimit on comma and add individual nutrients to array
  var finalveg = vegnutrients.split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < finalveg.length; i++) {
    //WHY CANT IT USE i TO ITERATE THROUGH vegnutrientvalues????
    var finalvnd = "<%= resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues %>";
    console.log(finalvnd[i][0].week1);
  }
</script>
```

But then the console reads `undefined` and the debugger shows this:

```
var finalvnd = "[object Object],";
console.log(finalvnd[i][0].week1);
```

But when I grab the data directly like this:

```
var finalvnd = "<%= resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues[0][0].week1 %>";
console.log(finalvnd);
```

It logs the correct value to the console, so I know the data is there, I just dont know how to properly access it. I want to use the `i` from the for loop as an index to grab the week1 value of the current nutrient. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your resultData is an array.
    resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues
Your vegnutrientsvalues is nested array then in that case u need to loop in resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues first and then through the each value of 
    finalveg[i].length

```
 for (var i = 0; i < finalveg.length;  finalvnd = "<%= 
    resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues %>";
    console.log(finalvnd[i][0].week1);
     <% for (var j = 0; j < finalveg[i].length; j++) {%>
  }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response! I'm still a little confused about this. `resultData` is a JSON object that has arrays in the `vegnutrientsvalues` field. Seeing as finalveg consists of two strings in this case, (`grow1` and `grow2`) so if I do `<% for (var j = 0; j < finalveg[i].length; j++) {%>` wont that just print the length of the string at index `i`? Say, for example, `finalveg[0]` is the string "grow1" so the `finalveg[0].length` would always equal 5 because thats the length of the string.

Comment: Would I want a nested for loop that first iterates thru `finalveg.length` and then somehow iterates through each element in `vegnutrientvalues` for that given index? I think that's what I'm trying to do but I'm getting stuck.

Comment: you also need to loop through this array resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do that? When I try to create a variable by grabbing this from EJS: `resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues` it shows up as `[object Object],` and prevents me from getting useful values out of it. Any ideas?

Comment: check the  typeof () variable. its an object or strng

Comment: When I do: `console.log(typeof <%= resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues %>);` it gives me an error in the console about the brackets being mismatched. This is what it shows in the debugger on Firefox: `console.log(typeof [object Object],);`

Comment: Hi, I think I figured it out. I had to use: `var finalvnd = <%- JSON.stringify(resultData[0].vegnutrientsvalues) %>;`

The `-` HTML escapes it whereas the `=` interpolates the value directly. I also had to put the JSON.stringify() inside the `<%- %>` instead of outside it.